# Uncaught Error: Cannot find module 'redux'

Tags: reactjs, webpack, redux, react-redux

I'm new to React..

This error came from Browser Console, while i'm trying to display it and also i'm working with django rest framework following the [Tutorial](https://youtu.be/BmL8iaLMnQ0) here. While trying to implement redux into my application i got this error. I don't know which part i missed.

```
Uncaught Error: Cannot find module 'redux'
    at webpackMissingModule (mapDispatchToProps.js:8)
    at eval (mapDispatchToProps.js:8)
    at Object../node_modules/react-redux/es/connect/mapDispatchToProps.js (main.js :452)
    at __webpack_require__ (main.js :999)
    at eval (connect.js:10)
    at Object../node_modules/react-redux/es/connect/connect.js (main.js :434)
    at __webpack_require__ (main.js :999)
    at eval (index.js:19)
    at Object../node_modules/react-redux/es/index.js (main.js :626)
    at __webpack_require__ (main.js :999)
webpackMissingModule @ mapDispatchToProps.js:8
eval @ mapDispatchToProps.js:8
./node_modules/react-redux/es/connect/mapDispatchToProps.js @ main.js :452
__webpack_require__ @ main.js :999
eval @ connect.js:10
./node_modules/react-redux/es/connect/connect.js @ main.js :434
__webpack_require__ @ main.js :999
eval @ index.js:19
./node_modules/react-redux/es/index.js @ main.js :626
__webpack_require__ @ main.js :999
eval @ App.js:6
./leadmanager/frontend/src/components/App.js @ main.js :52
__webpack_require__ @ main.js :999
eval @ index.js:2
./leadmanager/frontend/src/index.js @ main.js :129
__webpack_require__ @ main.js :999
(anonymous) @ main.js :1049
(anonymous) @ main.js :1051
:8001/favicon.ico:1 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you installed redux? react-redux and redux are two different packages, one is for its integration with react while the other one is the library per se, check if the redux package is in your node_modules folder, and try installing it if its not.

Comment: i installed "react-redux" but not "redux"... what command should i use for that

Comment: Open a terminal in your project's folder and type `npm install redux --save`

With `npm install` we are telling npm we want to install a new package. `redux` is the name of the package we want to install and `--save` tells to npm we want to track this package for our app to work properly.